# TFS History for specific method

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, history, changeset

I am looking for a change that created a specific method in a class. It would be best if I could get the entire changeset associated with creating that method. Annotate only shows last change, which was some sort of refactoring. History for the class is just too large to make finding all changes of the method easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you identify the file that you are interested in, in source control and then right click, view History you can see all of the changesets that have altered the file.

You can highlight 2 changesets (ctrl + click) and run a comparison between the 2 changesets.

do this a couple of times and you should be able to isolate when the method was added. you can then right click on the changeset where the method was introduced and choose changeset details to view everything that was included with that changeset

Comment: This is strange, but when I list History for that class I dont get all changesets. The records end in 2012 but in annotate I saw some changesets from 2008. Is it possible that I have to page history results? If so, how? I can't find any way to do that in VS.

Comment: has the file been branched? it is possible that it existed in a different branch and was then moved to this one, usually though you can drill down to see the previous branch history

Comment: Yes, i t was something like that. The last row could be clicked and the rest of the history unpacked.

Comment: Thank you. Easiest way was to find the refactor changeset in history, display the class from version just before the refactor happened (item in history just below). Annotate that version and there I found the correct changeset.